# How can I create a python console in VS Code that includes django app settings?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I got a little bit used to how PyCharm Professional works but I like Visual Studio Code way more, I like the Python console of PyCharm, which automatically includes things like `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. Is there a way to achieve something similar in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: you have to manually set python path in VS

Comment: @giveJob can you tell me how? I could not find anywhere how to do it. I only found about how to set the debugger for Django, but not the python terminal...

Comment: Have you tried anything outlined at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments?

Comment: @BrettCannon yes, but it tells you how to set the debugger profile. I want to open a Python terminal and be able to import functions/models from my modules and then do operations with them in the terminal, like ```Model.objects.all().delete()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I had to add the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in VS Code's settings.json to the terminal's environment with:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "application.settings"
},
```

I barely found how, but thanks @giveJob and @BrettCannon for trying to help